# I need to make a Discord bot, where I can make it so the ";time" command says the amount of time left until the timer hits zero

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I am making a countdown bot on Discord but need your help. I want to make it so you can update the amount of time left with ";time", and also so it automatically sends a message when the countdown hits zero. 
The following is my current code:

```
    from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import time
import asyncio

Client = commands.Bot(commands.when_mentioned_or('...'))
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=";", status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game(name="Counting"))

releasetime = 10
countdowndone = False

while releasetime >0:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("a")
    releasetime -=1

if releasetime <= 0:
    print("Countdown finished")
    countdowndone = True

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def time(ctx):
    global releasetime
    await bot.say("MineSaga will be up in" 'releasetime' "seconds.")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot ready")
    await bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name=";time", type=1))


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
   await bot.say(":ping_pong: Pong!")
```

Please help out by either rewriting the code or telling me tips.

Comment: By the way, while `releasetime >0:` is blocking and should not be executed in your main bot script, as it will not allow anything else to occur while it is running. This should be running in a bot.background_task()

Comment: Also, why do you create Client object if you then only use the extension Bot one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dextication said, using while here will block the whole bot. You need to update your timer in the background. The docs provide an [example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py) on how to setup one.

I'd then suggest you use a class to create your bot, keeping the updated timer in one of its attribute (let's say `self.timer`) the commands also defined as methods in this class (or an external cog) will then be able to access `self.timer` and add it in the answer to the command.